# Background Video/Animation on the website?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create something similar to this link, cannot find anything online, searched everywhere and still haven't found anything - How would I Create this effect?

I assume it could be HTML 5, but then how do I do it?

EDIT: Link here: http://roihunter.com/

EDIT 2: Also, apologies if the question was vague, but I couldn't think of scenario or a way to reword or how to code my own version, I was not after code, I was infact after a brief explanation and possibly a link or just a further understanding than what I knew.

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish this, but the way the website, you mentioned, is doing it specifically, is by using an HTML5 Video element and making it stretch 100% of the width of the page.

Comment: It's a video. View the source, check out the `<video>` element. It uses webm (here: http://roihunter.com/wp-content/themes/motionhouse/video/how-does-it-work.webm) with a fallback to mp4. There's no "effect" to be achieved here, it's just a plain old pre-rendered video.

Comment: Oh I see, so the actually way it is now I see the link, I couldn't work it out actually very impressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background video is fairly simple, just place a HTML5 video tag inside an absolute or fixed positioned div and make sure that gets behind your content like so:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1;">
    <video width="100%" height="100%">
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
Your content goes here.
```

Please note that you shouldn't use inline css, give a class to the div and place the CSS code in your stylesheet.

Comment: Hi Terwanerik, you actually supplied a really good answer and a combination of the comments and answers have helped me massively here. Thank you, I think I understand how it works and how to implement.

Comment: I have marked this as correct, however, what I do want to do is the future reader to read the comments on my question as that also helps.